# how to get coeefficient bandpass FIR Filter Design with Python

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, raspberry-pi, signal-processing, windowing

I'm trying to make a DSP with python, I am a beginner, like this site https://mbed.org/cookbook/FIR-Filte
1. I look for coefficients with python, but how to find the coefficient FIR bandpass using hamming window, can you give me an example?
2.  how to implement Coefficients to DSP using python in FIR bandpass using a Hamming window (I want to implement DSP with raspberry pi (first option) or on Arduino)

I'm not good in english, i hope you understand what I'm talking about,
thanks

Comment: your link is broken, btw - add an "r" at the end

Comment: yaah, its missing "r" in the link. thanks ben.

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques and approaches for designing FIR filters.  But if you just want a simple bandpass filter with n_pts points centered at f_c Hz (with sampling rate sr Hz), try:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
fir_coeff = np.hanning(n_pts)*np.cos(2.*np.pi*f_c/sr*np.arange(n_pts))
fir_coeff /= np.sum(np.hanning(n_pts))
filtered_signal = scipy.signal.lfilter(fir_coeff, 1.0, signal)
```

This is a reasonable bandpass filter, with Q about n_pts/(sr/f_c).  You increase the Q (make it a narrower bandpass filter) by increasing the filter length n_pts.

Note that if you're trying to implement filters on low-power hardware, you're much better off using IIR filters instead of FIR (if they suit your problem).  Thus, a similar filter can be implemented as

```
# Q = n_pts/(sr/f_c) or defined some other way
w_c = 2*pi*f_c/sr
beta = np.cos(w_c)
BW = w_c / Q
alpha = (1. - np.sin(BW))/np.cos(BW)
G = (1. - alpha)/2.
filtered_signal = scipy.signal.lfilter([G, 0, -G], [1, -beta*(1+alpha), alpha], signal)
```

For a reasonably narrow filter (n_pts = 33 or something), this should be an order of magnitude faster.

(The expressions are based on slide 14 of http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/e4810/lectures/L06-filters.pdf , this is what you learn in a DSP course).

Comment: thanks dpwe. I want to implement fir digial in speech recognition proccess,, and I have no idea how to use it.